# How to get size of DOM element when work with ng-show

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ng-show

All:

I wonder how to get the width and height of an Element if I set its ng-show false?

Like:

```
<button ng-click="show()">show</button>
<div id="showarea" style="width:50%; height:50%;" ng-show="showdiv"></div>
```

And in my controller:

```
$scope.showdiv = false;
$scope.show = function(){
    console.log( $("#showarea").width() );
}
```

This one only prints out 50(if I give a specific pixel number, it will get that number), I thought jQuery can not get the actual calculated value. But when I remove ng-show and use display:none; then jQuery can get the correct size. So I guess the ng-show must done some extra work which prevent jQuery to calculate the size.

Could anyone give a solution for this( any trick as long as we can solve the percentage situation)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When an element has a `ng-show` that is false, basically Angular applies a `ng-hide` class on the element that sets `display: none`.

Your test by manually setting `display: none` may have a problem somewhere, as it is expected that JavaScript (hence jQuery) is unable to calculate the size of that element.

If you really need to get the element width within your controller, you could use a custom `move-away` directive instead of `ng-show` like this:

```
module.directive('moveAway', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.moveAway, function(move) {
        if (move) {
          elem.addClass('moved-away');
        } else {
          elem.removeClass('moved-away');
        }
      });
    }
  };
})
```

And then add this CSS rule:

```
.moved-away {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100000px;
}
```

So instead of being hidden, the element would simply be put far away but keep its size.

NOTE: If you still have problems to get size on an absolutely positioned element (it happens when the width is something like `50%` rather than `50px`), you could try `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0.01` instead, but the element will still occupy the same spot in the DOM (even if not visible).

Comment: You can also get the element's dimension by setting its `visibility` property as `hidden` and its `display` property as `block` or empty.

Comment: Yes I added that at the same time as your comment, however the behavior will be different since when invisible, the element will occupy a place in the DOM, which may not be wanted since this doesn't happen with `display:none`

Comment: You're right. But it's possible to change the element's `display` property to `block`, get its dimensions and change it back to `none`. I do precisely that in [a directive I created](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput/blob/master/src/autosize.js), and I haven't seen any side effect (e.g. flickering) so far.

Comment: @floribon Thanks, as you said: "Your test by manually setting display: none may have a problem somewhere",  but the div do get hidden, and the width is calculated correctly when I resize the window, what other thing could be wrong to let jQuery get calculated?